# timeout for downloading a file

Tags: android, timeout, download

I am downloading a file using this way

```
URL url = new URL(URL)

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setConnectTimeout(TimeOut);
connection.setReadTimeout(TimeOut);
connection.connect();
String status = connection.getHeaderField(0);
```

what I want do is if the file is not downloaded in the specified time then 
it stops download or give **timeout Exception**.

I had `setConnectTimeout()` but only give exception if the connection is not established 
within the initial connection time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this, but I guess you could set a boolean variable to 'finished = false;' before you start downloading.
Then set this to 'finished = true;' when download is finished.
Then, create a thread that checks this variable on a regular interval or after the desired time. If the boolean value does not have the desired state, abort the download (disconnect connection, close the stream).

Also have a look at the AsyncTask-class.